# How do I split the string into an array at an index?

Tags: javascript

I need to split this string 3:00pm so it ends up as [3:00][pm]. Below is my attempt but it is not correct because the console prints `p m`.

```
date = '3:00pm'
var elem = date.slice(date.length-2);
```

Comment: [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) returns a string, not an array.  You probably want to use [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the two different parts with two different slices.

```js
var date = '3:00pm';
var arr = [
  date.slice(0, -2), // first to 2nd from last
  date.slice(-2) // just the last 2
];
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/\d+:\d+|\w+/g`

```js
var date = "3:00pm"
var elem = date.match(/\d+:\d+|\w+/g);
console.log(elem[0], elem[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex with positive lookahead.

```js
console.log("3:00pm".split(/(?=[ap]m)/));
console.log("11:55am".split(/(?=[ap]m)/));
```

Comment: Maybe need to check `am` too

Comment: That looks great. but may I know why regex and not a simple substring?

Comment: @mortezaT, just for fun.

Comment: That's a good point. I've tried that and I think works perfect most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var date = '3:00pm';

var time = date.substr(0, date.length - 2); // 3:00
var period = date.substr(date.length - 2);  // pm

console.log(time);
console.log(period);
```

Comment: I'd change the 4 in both spots to `date.length-2` or `-2` so that 10, 11, and 12 would also work, and remove the 2 in the period line

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to split not only `3:00pm` but also other times. Here is a sample using Regular Expression.

```
var re=/([0-9:]+)\s*(am|pm)/i;
var ar=[];
'3:00pm'.replace(re,function(m/*whole match ([0-9:]+)\s*(am|pm)*/, pt1/*([0-9:]+)*/, pt2/*(am|pm)*/){
  ar.push(pt1, pt2); //push captures
  return m; //do not change the string
});
console.log(ar); //["3:00","pm"]
```